# preg_match for td

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to filter data from a webpage inside td, it's something like this:

```
    <td colspan="2">several anchor,bold and other html tags are inside this td</td>
```

I have used this preg_match but its giving output of all other td, but in above case it is not giving any output.

```
    preg_match("/\<td colspan\=\"2\"\>(.*)\<\/td\>/",$str,$title);
```

Here is full td:

```
    <td colspan="2">
      <div align="left" style="width:370; height:315;">
            <ins style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px">      

          <ins style="display:block;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px" id="aswift_1_anchor"><iframe width="336" scrolling="no" height="280" frameborder="0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;" name="aswift_1" id="aswift_1" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){w.location.replace(h)}}" allowtransparency="true" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></ins></ins>
           </div><p>  When starting out sometimes it is a good idea to write down your            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline !important;position:static;font-family:inherit !important;font-weight:inherit !important;font-size:inherit !important;" class="kLink" id="KonaLink1">   
      <font color="blue" style="color: blue !important; font-family:inherit !important;font-weight:inherit !important;font-size:inherit !important;position:static;">                   <span style="color: blue !impor  If you seriously want to take back control of your money you need to build a <a href="http://ezinearticles.com/?To-Set-Up-a-Personal-Budget-Get-a-Pencil-and-Paper&amp;id=1629478">Personal Budget</a>. To learn more about creating a budget please visit the website <a href="http://household-budget.home-choices-net.com">Household Budgets by clicking here</a>. </p><p> </p><p><!-- google_ad_section_end -->

              </p><p>
        <font style="color:02679D; font-size:12"><b><font color="000000">Related Articles - 

       </font>
           </b></font>
        </p><p><table width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr>
        <td align="center">
           <br><br><br><br>

        <br><br>

          </font></p></td></tr></tbody></table>
            </p></td>
```

Comment: You do know that using regexps to parse HTML is wrong? (Well, controversial at least (unless you really know what you're doing))

Answer (score 1):

In general don't use regular expressions for parsing html. However your problem is that your regular expression is gready and catches all possible data. Try to add a question mark:

```
preg_match("/\<td colspan\=\"2\"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>/",$str,$title);
```

The question mark makes the group non gready and the string will end on the next possible mark.

Comment: Try ([^<]*?) instead of (.*?)

Comment: i am trying to match this  

</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2>  si have used this but not working            preg_match("/\<\/td\><\/tr\><tr\><td colspan\=2\>(.*)\<\/td\>/",$str,$title);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add modifier (s):

```
        preg_match("/\<td colspan\=\"2\"\>(.*)\<\/td\>/s",$str,$title);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> ```
>  s (PCRE_DOTALL)
> ```
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are
>   excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
>   negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
>   independent of the setting of this modifier.